# Need to change regex to accept trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that accepts payments and amounts below. Allows for formats with "$" "," and two decimal spaces. I need this regex to allow trailing spaces after the decimal places like so `'$50.00    '`

```
/^\$?[0-9 ][0-9\, ]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d])$/
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Did you actually try this out?  What happened?  Unless you provide a little more detail, your question is likely to get closed/put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s*` will capture [any whitespace](http://docforge.com/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_Types), including tabs and newlines:

```
/^\$?[0-9 ][0-9\, ]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d])\s*$/
```

If you're just trying to validate dollar values, I would make it a little simpler (although I don't know your exact use case):

```
/^\$?[0-9,]+(\.\d{2})?\s*$/
```

Comment: Note that this will not actually match `'$50.00 '`.

Comment: Actually that changes the pattern significantly. It will now no longer match `'$.50'`, which I assume OP wanted because there's an entire alternation for it. It will also match `',,,,,'`, which I assume OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `[ ]*` to the end should do the trick:

```
/^\$?[0-9 ][0-9\, ]*(\.\d{1,2})?[ ]*$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d])[ ]*$/
```

But you can simplify this by wrapping your alternatives in a group. Also note that you don't need to escape `,` or `.` inside a character class, and you don't need a character class at all if there is only character you want to match.

```
/^\$?(?:[0-9 ][0-9, ]*(\.\d{1,2})?|\.([\d][\d]))[ ]*$/
```